# produce intersection and decomposition lists with two generic lists

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose that we have two `List<int>`'s

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int> { 1, 3, 5, 7 , 9, 11, 18 };
List<int> list2 = new List<int> { 2, 3, 5, 7 , 9, 10, 20, 26, 36 };
```

question how can i produce;

```
intersect  {3, 5, 7, 9 }
list1Decomp  { 1, 11, 18 }
list2Decomp  { 2, 10, 20, 26, 36 }
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var intersection = list1.Intersect(list2).ToList();
var list1Decomp = list1.Except(intersection).ToList();
var list2Decomp = list2.Except(intersection).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

In short:

```
 intersect = list1.Intersect(list2);
 list1Decomp = list1.Except(list2);
 list2Decomp = list2.Except(list1);
```

These algorithms would be most efficient on an ordered collection (HashSet<> e.g.)

Also **beware** of using these algorithms on collections of custom types; they really need good IEquatable<> support (i.e. implement the interface and provide your own GetHashCode and Equals). Otherwise, the results will be *not what you expect*

Although you didn't ask, you might have:

```
 symmDifference = list1.Union(list2).Except(list1.Intersect(list2))
```

or

```
 symmDifference = new HashSet<int>(list1).SymmetricExceptWith(list2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var intersect = list1.Intersect(list2);
var list1Decomp = list1.Except(list2);
var list2Decomp = list2.Except(list1);
```